# Facebook share shows main server IP address instead of domain name

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I implemented social sharing features to application

We have load balancer set up which forwards all requests to main server so problem is Facebook sharing happening , but it shows IP address of main server .

Please suggest me how to remove IP address and show subdomain

[image]

Comment: Map a domain to the IP of your main server.

Comment: What do your Open Graph meta tags look like? What does the FB debug tool say?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following meta tag for facebook share

```
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
```

I think your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution , It was redirection issues , When the request redirects from one server to another server , it should be redirected without changing the url or to any ip address . It could be achieved like below

If the Redirection happens using virtual host file we can have

ex:

`ProxyPass "http://test.example.com/"`

If the Redirection happens using .htacess we can have

ex:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test.com\\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://test.com/test%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]`

Since the rewrite engine loops through all the rules until the URI stops changing, the L flag will not prevent the looping, only any further rules from getting applied in the current iteration.